# Cloud Solution without Flavors

Tags: cloud, openstack

On which cloud platform I can create servers with API with specific RAM, HDD and vCPU?

I've tried OpenStack, but it requires already saved specific Flavors.

Which is strange, I tought it's fully scalable solution for the hosting companies - what if the customer wants 512MB RAM with 40TB HD for example...

Answer (score 0):

[Softlayer](http://www.softlayer.com) has this.

Have a look at:
[build your own cloud server](http://www.softlayer.com/cloudlayer/build-your-own-cloud)